# Android wear sometimes doesn't recieve Messages from phone

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm working on an app to get sensor data from the watch. I start the acquisition using phone but there are instances when the watch and phone seem to be perfectly connected but when I send the 'start acquisition' command nothing happens. The watch has to be restarted to start accepting the command then.

This is how I'm building the connection from the phone:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(MainActivity.this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

This is how I'm sending the Data from the phone:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() ) {

        final PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest.create("/toWear");
        putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putInt("duration", duration); // Duration of data, selected in TimeSelector
        putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putString("type", type);
        putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putString("name", name);
        putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putString("Starting Time", startingTime); // Starting Time of data
        putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putBoolean("Stop", false); //Stop is set True when Phone has to stop watch from taking data
        putDataMapReq.setUrgent();
        PutDataRequest request = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest();
        Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
            }
        });

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Not Connected properly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

This is how I'm accepting the data in the smartwatch:

```
  public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    count=0;
    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

    for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            // DataItem changed
            DataItem item = event.getDataItem();

            if (item.getUri().getPath().compareTo("/toWear") == 0) {
                DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).getDataMap();


                int duration = dataMap.getInt("duration");
                stop=dataMap.getBoolean("Stop");
                String type = dataMap.getString("type");
                String name = dataMap.getString("name");
                String startingTime= dataMap.getString("Starting Time");
                //  updateCount(dataMap.getInt(COUNT_KEY));


                Bundle b= new Bundle();
                b.putInt("duration",duration);
                b.putString("Starting Time",startingTime);

                if(!stop) {
                    AcquisitionStatus=true;
                    setAcquisitionStatus(true);
                    Intent sensorServ = new Intent(MyService.this, SensorService.class);
                    sensorServ.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    sensorServ.putExtras(b);
                    startService(sensorServ);

                }
                else {
                    AcquisitionStatus = false;
                    setAcquisitionStatus(false);
                }

            }
        } else if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
            // DataItem deleted
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know, why is it that sometimes, despite a proper connection having been established, the smartwatch fails to receive the data from the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Android Wear Data API ensures 100% transmission of data. If the two data are same, then the data isn't sent as it doesn't update anything on the screen. Check whether the data are the same.

Comment: Thank you but the Data is not the same. I'm sending the data acquired from 3 sensors over a period of 10 seconds. With a sampling frequency of 100hz.

Comment: Let us assume you are sending three data. Is the last sent data missing or the data in the middle or first? If the data in middle is missing, then it might be updated with the next value. For example, if you had sent a type with a value "10" and after 10 sec, if you're sending another data with the value "15", there are a higher rate of chances only the recent values are sent to the wear. Because the data aren't sent as soon as they are generated. Android queues it and processes it. Can you check once whether the data in the middle or last is being lost?

Comment: Assuming 3 data are sent. This is what happens, in 20% of cases all 3 will be sent. In the other 80% cases, the data at the end misses. Like, e.g I wouldn't get the 3rd one, or if I don't get the 2nd one, I'd miss on the 3rd one too. As soon as I miss 1 data, the ones coming after it are also lost.

Comment: Have you read this: Note: A successful result code does not guarantee delivery of the message. If your app requires data reliability, consider using DataItem objects or the ChannelClient class to send data between devices.

Comment: this is the link https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html